# Reason for P being a primitive function

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I asked this question before a few days, but I made some progress in explanation, so I just want to check if it is okay.

I am supposed to give reasons why function P is a primitive function. I have to explain it as a general method for determination of area or volume of geometric figures.

My explanation:

Primitive function is a function, whose derivation is equal to original function: $$P^{}{}'(x)=f(x)$$ We know that:$${P}'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ and we have to show that limit of the function is equal to f(x).

We have function f, which is nonnegative and defined on interval $$\left \langle a,b \right \rangle$$ For all t, which belong to interval $$\left \langle a,b \right \rangle$$ is P(t) area of figure label int the picture below.

For small h,h>0, is area of the figure P(t+h)-P(t) label in the picture with black colour.

Functional value for f(x) and f(t) for x, which belongs to $$t\leq x\leq t+h$$ are different only a little, concretely:$$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x:t\leq x\leq t+\delta ) is \left | f(x)-f(t) \right |\leq \epsilon $$ so$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{P(t+h)-P(t)}{h}=f(t) $$[image]

Is it correct? Thanks